# While within a switch block

Tags: c++, switch-statement, while-loop, unreachable-code

I've seen the following code, taken from the [libb64 project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libb64).
I'm trying to understand what is the purpose of the while loop within the switch block -

```
switch (state_in->step)
    {
        while (1)
        {
    case step_a:
            do {
                if (codechar == code_in+length_in)
                {
                    state_in->step = step_a;
                    state_in->plainchar = *plainchar;
                    return plainchar - plaintext_out;
                }
                fragment = (char)base64_decode_value(*codechar++);
            } while (fragment < 0);
            *plainchar    = (fragment & 0x03f) << 2;
    case step_b:
            do {
                if (codechar == code_in+length_in)
                {
                    state_in->step = step_b;
                    state_in->plainchar = *plainchar;
                    return plainchar - plaintext_out;
                }
                fragment = (char)base64_decode_value(*codechar++);
            } while (fragment < 0);
            *plainchar++ |= (fragment & 0x030) >> 4;
            *plainchar    = (fragment & 0x00f) << 4;
    case step_c:
            do {
                if (codechar == code_in+length_in)
                {
                    state_in->step = step_c;
                    state_in->plainchar = *plainchar;
                    return plainchar - plaintext_out;
                }
                fragment = (char)base64_decode_value(*codechar++);
            } while (fragment < 0);
            *plainchar++ |= (fragment & 0x03c) >> 2;
            *plainchar    = (fragment & 0x003) << 6;
    case step_d:
            do {
                if (codechar == code_in+length_in)
                {
                    state_in->step = step_d;
                    state_in->plainchar = *plainchar;
                    return plainchar - plaintext_out;
                }
                fragment = (char)base64_decode_value(*codechar++);
            } while (fragment < 0);
            *plainchar++   |= (fragment & 0x03f);
        }
    }
```

What can give the while? It seems that anyway, always the switch will perform only one of the cases. Did I miss something?

Thanks.

Comment: Seems to me that they just swapped the while statement and the switch statement so that the switch was on the outside instead.

Comment: Way too complex, should be refactored.

Comment: I think I just got a headache.

Comment: Great example of *how to comment complex code* ... or is it an example of *self-documenting* code?

Comment: Stop weeping.. Duff's device rules.

Comment: The do/while-loops are basically identical... Should be possible to just have it before the first case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although this is Duff's Device, this version is not about implementing a loop-unrolling optimisation but rather to implement an iterator over a Base64 encoded stream. So you can do something like this:

```
Base64Stream stream; // the base64 data

char c;

while ((c == stream->NextChar ()) != 0)
{
  // do something with c
}
```

In the given code, the first switch us used to jump back to where the previous `return` exited, and then the while (1) allows the iteration loop to continue indefinately. However, there's no protection against a buffer overrun in this function.

In C#, there is a neater solution to this, the `yield` statement.

Answer (score 3):

Like Kenny says, this code looks like a Duff's device.  [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff's_device) is what Wikipedia says about it.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an attempt of implementing a Duff's device, then it's probably misplaced.

Note that in the case of Duff's device, as described in Wikipedia, the loop is finite, while in the code presented above it's a neverending loop. The only possibility for it to finish is satisfaction of the (codechar == code_in+length_in) condition (code_id and length_in are immutable in the code snippet, though).

I doubt it will even work as a Duff's device, i.e. that it will result in proper loop expansion by the compiler.